# How to find the longest chord of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ passing through $(0,-b)$?

Tags: geometry

Let $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ be an ellipse. How to find the longest chord in such ellipse which passes through the point $(0,-b)$ when

1. $\ a> \sqrt{2}b>0$,
2. $\ 0<a\leq \sqrt{2}b$

Frankly I do not even know what should I use. Is using the formula for the distance between two points and than maximization the expression a good idea? How the cases affect the solution?

Comment: Why from the origin? The chord can't begin or end in origin.

Comment: See [this document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/278671459_Extreme_Lengths_for_Chords_of_an_Ellipse/figures)

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi You are right.

Comment: @enzotib you were right. That made me aware of a mistake which I have done. I forgot to add that this chord must pass through the point $(0,-b)$. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Novice, yeah, I removed my comment

Comment: So, when $a\leq b$ the chord is the vertical one, of length $2b$

Comment: @enzotib unfortunately I don't have such case. See the question.

Comment: Assume a line through (0,b). Find intersection with ellipse (one will be the point (0,b)). Differentiate the distance to find maximum.

Comment: @Novice $a<\sqrt{2}b$ comprise also $a\leq b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be the coordinates of the other end of the chord, with $x_1>0$ (the solution is symmetric with respect to $y$-axis, so this is not a limitation).

The condition to impose is: the tangent in $(x_1,y_1)$ should be orthogonal to the chord. The tangent is
$$
t:\ \frac{xx_1}{a^2}+\frac{yy_1}{b^2}=1
$$
A vector normal to the tangent is given from the coefficients of variables $x,y$ in the cartesian equation of the line,
$$
\mathbf{n}_t=\left(\frac{x_1}{a^2},\frac{y_1}{b^2}\right)
$$
while a directional vector of the line, orthogonal to $\mathbf{n},$ is
$$
\mathbf{u}_t=\left(-\frac{y_1}{b^2},\frac{x_1}{a^2}\right)
$$

The parametric equations of the line on which the chord lies is
$$
\begin{alignedat}{2}
x &= &&0+(x_1-0)t,\\
y &= -&&b+(y_1+b)t.
\end{alignedat}
$$
This is built with the formula for the parametric equations of the line through two points $A=(x_A,y_A)$ and $B=(x_B,y_B)$:
$$
c:\ \left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
x &= x_A+(x_B-x_A)t,\\
y &= y_A+(y_B-y_A)t.
\end{alignedat}
\right.
$$
Its directional vector is given by the coefficients of the parameter $t$
$$
\mathbf{u}_c=(x_1,y_1+b).
$$

The orthogonality condition
$$
\mathbf{u}_t\cdot\mathbf{u}_c=0
$$
gives
$$
-\frac{x_1y_1}{b^2}+\frac{x_1(y_1+b)}{a^2}=0
$$
and when $x_1\neq0$ we have
\begin{align}
y_1 &= \frac{b^3}{a^2-b^2}\\
x_1 &= a\sqrt{1-y_1^2/b^2}=\frac{a^2\sqrt{a^2-2b^2}}{a^2-b^2}
\end{align}
The square root requires $a\geq\sqrt{2}b>b.$
The length of the arc is
$$
l=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.
$$
When $0<a\leq\sqrt{2}b$ the only solution is for $x_1=0$ and the chord is the vertical one.

This is an animation for fixed $b$ and $a$ decreasing

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you about formula you used in finding equation of chord  and which orthogonality condition have you used? I can't find it.

Comment: @Novice I enlarged the answer with more details

Comment: Thanks. Why _a directional vector of the line, orthogonal to_ $\mathbf{n},$ _is_ 
$\mathbf{u}_t=\left(-\frac{y_1}{b^2},\frac{x_1}{a^2}\right)$? When I am doing inner product, I don't recieve zero (or maybe $\mathbf{n}\neq \mathbf{n}_t$). Also it confuses me how the length of arc is evaluated. Sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: @Novice (1) in 2D a vector orthogonal to $(a,b)$ is $(-b,a)$, in fact $(a,b)\cdot(-b,a)=a(-b)+ba=-ab+ab=0.$ (2) In the inner product you don't receive zero, you have to impose that it is zero. (3) the lenght of the chord is $\sqrt{(x_B-x_A)^2+(y_B-y_A^2)}=\sqrt{x_1^2+(y_1+b)^2}=\dots$

Comment: @Novice I should add that I used vectors because it is simpler for me, but you can repeat calculation writing the equations of lines in the form $y=mx+n$ and impose orthogonality through $mm'=-1.$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Novice I added an animation